# How to replace text with image in html

Tags: html

I have this code and i want to replace the "text example" with a image of my own.
I tried replacing it with CSS but i made it worst.

Thanks in advance.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-b navbar-trans navbar-expand-md fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll" href="#page-top">text example</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use this format ? `<a> <img src=" Image_URL" alt = " Image_describtion"></a>`

Comment: @George show us please what did you try, so we can help here. if I am in your place I would not use images you can use font-awesome instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
<a class="navbar-brand js-scroll" href="#page-top">
     <img src="..." alt="Image_description">
</a>
```

if you are using the bootstrap CDN you can add more styles if you prefer
and then try using

```
<a class="navbar-brand js-scroll" href="#page-top">
     <img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</a>
```